# How to upload application in MacOS Apple Store

Tags: java, dmg, xcrun, notarize, cfbundleidentifier

I want to publish an Java application into Apple Store. The apple documentation recommends to use

```
$ xcrun altool --validate-app -f file -t platform -u username [-p password] [--output-format xml]
$ xcrun altool --upload-app -f file -t platform -u username [-p password] [—output-format xml]
```

First I tried to use a dmg file, but I always got an error. Then I found in internet that I should use a zip file.
When using the zip, I got this error:

xcrun altool --validate-app --file DbSchemaMac.zip -t osx --username "..." --password "..."
2020-11-27 18:34:21.517 altool[22912:4098310] *** Error: Unable to validate archive 'DbSchemaMac.zip': (
"Error Domain=ITunesSoftwareServiceErrorDomain Code=-20008 "The Info.plist indicates an iOS app, but submitting a pkg or mpkg." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The Info.plist indicates an iOS app, but submitting a pkg or mpkg., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.}"
)

The Info.plist looks like here. What could be wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
<plist version="0.9">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>DbSchema</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>JavaApplicationStub</string>
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>app.icns</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleSignature</key>
<string>????</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.dbschema.dbschema</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>8.3.3</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>8.3.3</string>
<key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
<string>8.3.3</string>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
<true/>
<key>LSHasLocalizedDisplayName</key>
<true/>

<!-- I4J_INSERT_DOCTYPE -->
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
<key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
<array>
<string>dbs</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
<string>DbSchema project file</string>
<key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
<string>Viewer</string>
</dict>
</array>
<!-- I4J_INSERT_URLTYPE -->
<key>i4j.baseDir</key>
<string>$APP_PACKAGE/../</string>
<key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
<string>10.11</string>
<key>i4j.appId</key>
<string>0607-8447-0273-3287</string>
<key>i4j.allowPassthrough</key>
<true/>
<key>i4j.minVersion</key>
<string>12</string>
<key>i4j.maxVersion</key>
<string>15</string>
<key>i4j.allowBeta</key>
<true/>
<key>i4j.vmIdPrefix</key>
<string></string>
<key>JavaVM</key>
<dict>
<key>MainClass</key>
<string>com.install4j.runtime.launcher.MacLauncher</string>
<key>VMOptionArray</key>
<array>
<string>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</string>
<string>-Dprism.maxvram=2G</string>
<string>-Xmx512M</string>
<string>-Xms64M</string>
<string>-Dinstall4j.launcherId=30</string>
<string>-Dinstall4j.swt=false</string>
<string>-Dexe4j.moduleName=$APP_PACKAGE</string>
</array>
<key>OptionsFile</key>
<string>$APP_PACKAGE/Contents/vmoptions.txt</string>
<key>ArgumentArray</key>
<array>
</array>
<key>SearchSequence</key>
<array>
<string>Y</string>
<string>EJAVA_HOME</string>
<string>EJDK_HOME</string>
</array>
<key>VersionInfo</key>
<string>0_2982400925</string>
<key>SplashFile</key>
<string>$APP_PACKAGE/../.install4j/s_1vuio0g.png</string>
<key>ClassPath</key>
<string>$APP_PACKAGE/../.install4j/i4jruntime.jar:$APP_PACKAGE/../lib/*</string><!-- I4J_INSERT_CLASSPATH -->
<key>WorkingDirectory</key>
<string>$APP_PACKAGE/../.</string>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```